# In which way we add the new element into the sorted list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Can you explain to me the func()(add a new element into the already sorted list)? I don`t understand how we add the previous pointer to the new one. My logic imagines it in a next way:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vugbk.png)

```
#include <iostream>
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};
void func(node** lis, int n) {
    if (*lis == nullptr || (*lis)->data > n) {
        auto temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = *lis;
        *lis = temp;
    }
    else func(&(*lis)->next, n);
}

void funcP(node* lis) {
    while (lis)
    {
        std::cout << lis->data;
        lis = lis->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    node* l = new node;
    node* head = new node;
    head = l;
    l->next = nullptr;
    l->data = 5;

    node* a = new node;
    l->next = a;
    a->data = 6;
    a->next = nullptr;

    l = l->next;

    node* q = new node;
    l->next = q;
    q->data = 9;
    q->next = nullptr;
    
    l = head;

    func(&l, 7);
    funcP(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your logic is ignoring this line `*lis = temp`. That's the line that adds the new node into the proper place in the list.

Comment: `lis` will either be a pointer to a `next` field or a pointer to the head of the list. If the new node being being added anywhere after the first node, then the two lines `temp->next = *lis; *lis = temp;` insert the new node in the correct position in the list.